# How to run a thread step by step using a jButton

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, wait

i have a thread running which keeps repainting the maze recursively until the exit is reached. The method below is responsible for repainting the maze.

```
private void moveFromStep(int x, int y) {
        if(step){
            if(isWall(x,y))
                return ;
            if(isVisited(x,y))
                return ;
            if(isGoal(x,y)){
                free = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Solution Complete: finish reachable");
            }
            if(!free){
                    step = false;
                    setVisited(x,y);
                    repaint();
                    //try {Thread.sleep(3000);} catch (Exception e) { }
                    //try {wait();} catch (Exception e) { }
                    moveFromStep(x-1,y);
                    moveFromStep(x+1,y);
                    moveFromStep(x,y-1);
                    moveFromStep(x,y+1);            
            }
        }   
   }
```

now i have a JPanel running separately and i want to repaint it step by step.
i want to do this by using a "Step" button. So like the maze is printed step by step when "Step" button is pressed. The code below is the action listener for the buttons

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            String action = event.getActionCommand();
            MazeStep mazeStep = new MazeStep();
            Thread mazeThreadStep = null;

            if (action.equals("Load Maze")) {
                mazeAnim.readFile(getName());
                //mazeStep = new MazeStep();
                mazeStep.readFile(getName());
            }
            else if(action.equals("Start")){
                JFrame world = new JFrame();
                mazeStep = new MazeStep();
                mazeStep.readFile(getName());
                world.setSize(300, 300);
                world.setTitle("Maze solver");
                world.setContentPane(mazeStep);
                world.setVisible(true);
                mazeThreadStep = new Thread(mazeStep);
                mazeThreadStep.start();
            }
            if(action.equals("Step")){
                mazeStep.step = true;
                synchronized (mazeThreadStep) {
                    mazeThreadStep.notify();
                  }
            }

    }
```

So can anyone help me what could be done in order to achieve this plz.

Comment: Where does your step method "wait"?

Comment: Its in the moveFromStep() method after repaint() but ive comment it out coz i couldn't make it work